# Sequelize findAll order by value position

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize and I want order by value of position. I think Sequelize gives results randomly.

**Here is my query:**

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const value = req.body.value

    Titles.findAll({
        where: 
            { [Op.or]: [
                {title: { [Op.iLike]: '%' + value + '%'}},
                {titleLink: { [Op.iLike]: '%' + value + '%'}}
            ]
        },
        attributes: ['id', 'title', 'titleLink', 'entryCount'],

        ///limit: 10,
    }).then(result => {
        res.json({'titles': result})
    })
    //res.send({results: req.body})
})
```

It gives results looks like this

**Value:** test

**Results:**

1. Test Title
2. Test Title 2
3. Test
4. Example Test

**Results (I want):**

1. Test
2. Test Title 1
3. Test Title 2
4. Example Test

Answer (score 1):

*If `Titles` has a field `position` then you can simply use the order property as mentionned in [the doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#ordering) (or use the `id` field) :*

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const value = req.body.value

    Titles.findAll({
        where: 
            { [Op.or]: [
                {title: { [Op.iLike]: '%' + value + '%'}},
                {titleLink: { [Op.iLike]: '%' + value + '%'}}
            ]
        },
        attributes: ['id', 'title', 'titleLink', 'entryCount'],
        order: [['position', 'ASC']],

        ///limit: 10,
    }).then(result => {
        res.json({'titles': result})
    })
    //res.send({results: req.body})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case it resolved

***import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';***

before:
**order: ['created_at']**

after:
**order: Sequelize.literal('created_at DESC'),**

good look
Happy 2020